# Multiplication not working in calculated expression

Tags: sql, oracle21c

I am trying to multiply the below two number fields together in a query:

```
SELECT 
(COALESCE(UNIT_PRICE , 0) * COALESCE(QUANTITY, 0))
FROM PO_LINES_ALL LINE
```

This results in blank values output. As you can see below `UNIT_PRICE` can either be a whole number or a decimal. Is there something I need to change to get the multiplication working correctly?

[image]

**EDIT:**

If I include these two columns in the Select, then the calculated expression works. Is that the only way for the multiplication expression can work?

```
SELECT 
(COALESCE(UNIT_PRICE , 0) * COALESCE(QUANTITY, 0)), UNIT_PRICE, QUANTITY
FROM PO_LINES_ALL LINE
```

Comment: Including those columns shouldn't change the results of the other columns - it looks like you're running into a wrong results bug. Oracle can potentially hold data in many different locations - table, index, buffer cache, result cache, materialized view, etc. Most likely only *one* of those places is storing bad data, and when you added unnecessary columns you unintentionally changed the location of the data. Compare the explain plans by running `explain plan for select ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)` for both statements and post the full text output here.

Comment: It's also possible that there is a plan management feature that is changing only one specific form of the query. For example, it's possible to use DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE to intercept the query and replace it with a different version that returns different results. If there's something weird like that going on here, the "Note" section at the bottom of the explain plan will probably point to the problem. The solution may be removing the plan management feature, or maybe rebuilding a corrupt index (if only the plan that uses an index is broken).